# How can I add all the email files from a pst file to a sharepoint library (inclusive the mail columns: from, to, cc, subject etc)

Tags: email, library

I am using sharepoint 2010. I have a pst file. This is a Outlook data file. In this file are all the emails stored. How can I send all these emails to a sharepoint library. I would like also to send each email with the email columns : from, to, cc, subject etc. Is this possible? I am a developer so if there is some programmatically solution it is also ok.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an Outlook add-on where it is possible to send email files to a SharePoint library. The email metadata is also sended to SharePoint columns.

Comment: Can you share what plugin you found?